# Mock a HEAD request for a redirect (via nock module)

Tags: node.js, redirect, mocha.js, nock

In my project i try to expand tweets to be fully displayed. Links shorted by bit.ly are expanded by this peace of code (found @ stackoverflow).

```
function expandUrl(shortUrl,callback) {
  debug("expandUrl");
  request( { method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
    function (error, response) {
      if (error) return callback(null,shortUrl);
      return callback(null,response.request.href);
    }
  );
}
```

To have no need to be online during mocha tests, i would like to nock this part of code with the following:

```
nock('http://bit.ly')
      .intercept("/1Ghc7dI","HEAD")
      .reply(200,undefined,{location:"http://discoverspatial.com/courses/qgis-for-beginners"});
```

But this is not working. response.request.href is "undefined" after this job. (i tried href instead of location, this makes no difference.

Comment: Do you actually want a `301`, `302`, or `307` response? `200` appears to be the wrong response code for what you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To give a redirect you need to set the status to a HTTP URL redirection status as @apsillers says in the comments. Also if you don't want to be online, you need to nock the destination url as well, since request will call it to check that it's not a redirect:

```
nock('http://bit.ly')
      .intercept("/1Ghc7dI","HEAD")
      .reply(301,undefined,{location:"http://discoverspatial.com/courses/qgis-for-beginners"});

nock('http://discoverspatial.com')
      .intercept("/courses/qgis-for-beginners", "HEAD")
      .reply(200,"OK");
```